# PHP / jQuery / Nestable Handling reordered form field arrays

Tags: php, jquery

Maybe I'm overthinking this but I have a form like such...

```
<form method="post" action="act.php">
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[0][name]" value="Mike">
     <input name="item[0][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[1][name]" value="Joe">
     <input name="item[1][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   etc...
</form>
```

Which can be reordered like this...

```
<form method="post" action="act.php">
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[1][name]" value="Joe">
     <input name="item[1][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[0][name]" value="Mike">
     <input name="item[0][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   etc...
</form>
```

and my act.php is...

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['item']); $x++ ) {
   $values = $_POST['item'][$x];
   ... query to insert values ...
}
```

The question I have is what is the best practice for submitting the form with the items in the properly ordered "visible" sequence. Is renaming the inputs the best way to do this or is there some better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was overthinking it, the fix is to call array_values() on the $_POST['item'] variable before processing its data.

Answer (score -1):

Take the numeric indexes out of the HTML. PHP will then assign indexes in the order that the inputs are sent.

```
<form method="post" action="act.php">
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[][name]" value="Mike">
     <input name="item[][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   <div class="reorderable">
     <input name="item[][name]" value="Joe">
     <input name="item[][id]" value="1">
   </div>
   etc...
</form>
```

Comment: This does not work. I did figure out how to fix it by simply reindexing the $_POST['item'] variable with array_values().

See testing page here...
http://choreobook.com/test.php